# how to choose product type in order to have this kind of store

Tags: product-attribute, custom-options, magento-community, magento-connect

I want to compose final product for my food store:
a product named sandwish (that can be grouped,im not sure) with simple products : tomato , tuna ... My customer can remove tomato and choose mushroom (another simple product) the goal is to have one product at the end on cart page.

Answer (score 1):

Magento grouped products work in a bit different way - you add all ingredients as associated simple products and then the client selects that, for example, he wants 1 portion of tomatoes, 2 slices of cheese, 1 tuna and 0 sausages. The price is calculated on the basis of ingredients.  It is not possible to remove unused for sandwiches items, but the client can leave 0 for ingredients that he does not want. 
Here is screenshot of example I have created in my test store - 
[image]

Comment: I see thats exactly what i want,but please can you explain more how you did this

Comment: I tried this but it gives me different product on my cart with chosen simple product name! but me i want one final product on my cart

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that you need one product in the cart, I guess group products will not be a good fit. Maybe you can try to create it as simple products with 'checkbox' custom option?
At website  it will look like this -
[image]

When you add product to cart it will be single item -
[image]

I also want to remind you a drawback of custom options - you will not be able to track the quantity of components. If it is not a problem, you can create your products this way.

Comment: yes that's what i did finally ,but now i have another issue ,is that  i have to show products list of catégory and choose ingredients from there and not in product page.(show those custom options on products list and have the ability to choose ingredient and add to cart)

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is layered navigation - left sidebar with the filter. It is no default possibility  to add custom options to layered navigation. Only attributes can be added there.